# Polymer core-header-panel and on-scroll

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

I'm using `<core-drawer-panel/>` and `<core-header-panel/>` to layout my app.
Inside `<core-header-panel/>` I have `<core-toolbar/>` and `<div/>` elements.

Now, when I set a content into DIV element (which is a list of element) it becomes scrollable.  I want to load next part of content automatically when the user scrolls down to the last element. 
The problem is that I can't access to scroll event on `<core-header-panel/>`. Event is fired inside this element on #mainContainer div. I can't access this event from `<core-header-panel/>`.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

Comment: I've logged a ticket on their issue tracker. In the meantime, have a look at this post as it's most likely the solution for you :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682104/core-scroll-header-panel-jquery-scroll

Comment: Why don't you create a new listener for it. `Polymer.dom('core-header-panel').listener.ontrack` ?